# Cypress aborts XHR requests if running in Cypress docker containers

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'm having a test which uses cy.route().

This is how it looks in debug:

```
1114 [2019-11-19T08:19:31.373Z] ⚠ error (network): Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

1115 URL: http://localhost:3000/__cypress/xhrs/http://localhost:3000/api/identity/public/pre-login
```

On my local env all tests run ok, but on gitlab ci I get some requests aborted. I use Cypress docker images, also tried npm docker images.

[image]

Is there a fix for this issue?

---

Looks like the problem returned after 4.0 release. Even with nginx.

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? I'm getting the same thing in the same circumstances but with just XHR not stub.

Comment: My requests are been aborted also

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in express web server. I built all the statics, and served them with the help of express server. I moved to nginx, and everything became ok.